# Windows 7 36TB RAID6 -- "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, raid

I am doing a RAID upgrade project, installing an 8x6TB (36TB effective size) RAID6 array using an Areca ARC-1222 controller, and then transferring data from an older 8x3TB (12TB effective size) RAID10 on a different controller.

I have created the raidset and volume in the controller's bios, allowed the RAID initialization to complete, booted Windows 7 successfully, and Disk Management sees the new RAID array as well as the old. I successfully created a GPT partition and performed a quick format to NTFS. However when I try to create a folder in the root of the new volume I get the error

```
Could not find this item
This is no longer located in Computer. Verify the item's location and try again
RAID6 Storage
Space free: 32.7TB
Total size: 32.7TB
```

In the Disk Management console the disk shows as Online, and the volume shows `Healthy (Primary Partition)`. If I try to delete the partition using Disk Management, I get the error

```
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I'm at a loss how to proceed here. Everything seems to be configured correctly but I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Is Event Viewer showing any obvious errors in its System (or, less likely, Application) logs?

Comment: @DanielB there is a Warning in the Windows Logs->System section, from service Ntfs which says `The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur.` This seems to have occurred each time I tried to delete or format the partition (including when I tried using DISKPART in the command line)

Comment: Are you sure your Areca controller is working properly? I never had that warning. Although it is just that: a warning, not an error. Did you try rebooting?

Comment: Yeah I've even swapped the controller with the whole attached array into another win7 machine with a clean OS install, everything works great there. This sounds like an issue with the specific Win7 install :(

Comment: Never did get this working. We tried all sorts of things including temporarily turning off page files in Windows, fiddling with every setting the RAID controller exposes, disconnecting all drives besides the RAID and the boot drive, updating the motherboard BIOS firmware, etc. We eventually gave up and went to an external raid enclosure, which is working fine.